# Clamp rotation of a follow camera when its target is falling

Tags: unity, c#, camera, transformation

I'm using this camera script to follow a cube. The cube has rigid body with gravity enabled. There is a plane on which the cube moves. If it goes off the plane, the cube starts falling. However when it falls, the camera starts rotating in all directions. Here is the script. Is there any way to clamp the rotation so that when the cube falls, the camera moves only in the y direction, with no rotation?

```
[SerializeField] Transform target;
public Vector3 defaultDist = new Vector3(0f, 10, -9f);
[SerializeField] float distDamp = .1f;

public Vector3 velocity = Vector3.one;

Transform myT;


void Awake()
{
    myT = transform;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    SmoothFollow();
    
}

void SmoothFollow()
{
    Vector3 toPos = target.position + (target.rotation * defaultDist); 

    Vector3 curPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(myT.position, toPos,ref velocity ,distDamp);
    myT.position = curPos ;      

    myT.LookAt(target, target.up);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling LookAt using Target.up instead of Vector3.up.

LookAt takes that Vector so that it can do natural "turret" rotation. Without it, a regular RotateTowards operation doesn't know which axis to rotate. For example, if you wanted to rotate something to face 180 degrees backwards, the system wouldn't know if you want it to turn only on the Y-axis or do a flip backwards over the X axis while rolling on the Z axis.

When you provide an "up" direction for LookAt, it will swivel along that axis. It allows you to do things like have turrets and wheels on slanted surfaces that swivel correctly- instead of Vector3.up, you use the slanted surface normal.

I ran your code and confirmed that changing Target.up to Vector3.up fixes the rotation issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's working properly now...

Comment: Awesome, feel free to mark the question as answered